# asp.net - validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

im getting this error when i click my radio button, what is the solution for this------

invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: can you please post part of code.

Comment: http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=invalid+postback+or+callback+argument.+EnableEventValidation%3D%22true%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post back is failing validation. Some suspicous character(s) are being posted back to the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx